# DevExpress XtraGrid Problem

Tags: excel, gridview

I want to show excel data in DevExpress data grid. The problem that I am facing is as follows:-

1. I select one worksheet from excel work book and display it in data grid, this works fine but,
2. When I select another worksheet from same same excel workbook it appends all the columns to the previous view. I want to remove all previous columns. I tried to remove from column collection but it did not work. I also tried to call PopulateColumns() method of the view but it also did not work.

Please help.

Thanks,
Omkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!!!! we need to call Clear() method on Column collection of the grid... :)